# Installing packages on PopOS with TeXLive's tlmgr

Tags: packages, texlive, tlmgr

I am trying to install `tcolorbox` package but getting this, I am using [PopOS](https://system76.com/pop)

```
$tlmgr install tcolorbox
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
(see /usr/share/doc/texlive-base/README.tlmgr-on-Debian.md)

tlmgr: Local TeX Live (2020) is older than remote repository (2021).
Cross release updates are only supported with
  update-tlmgr-latest(.sh/.exe) --update
See https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html for details.
```

I have followed the `update-tlmgr-latest` step and tried to update and it is saying

```
/usr/share/texlive$ sh update-tlmgr-latest.sh -- --upgrade
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing TeX Live Manager Updater  100%  
./runme.sh: Cannot find TeX Live root using kpsewhich --var-value=SELFAUTOPARENT.
./runme.sh: (no tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb and/or tlpkg/tlpobj/.)
./runme.sh: Please set your PATH as needed, otherwise it's hopeless.
```

Comment: you are using the debian system supplied tex not the upstream texlive from tug, you should install things using `apt` or whatever  linux package manager you use. `sudo apt update texlive-xxx` whichever of the debian packages has this (do you really not have it already?)

Comment: `$sudo apt install texlive`
`$sudo apt install texlive-latex-base`
`$sudo apt install texlive-latex-extra `
I installed texlive using these commands but I want to install the [tcolorbox](https://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) package how do I install it?

Comment: use `apt-file` to figure out which debian package provides `tcolorbox`. It should be a part of `texlive-latex-extra` depending on the TeXLive version your popos version installed. Are yuo sure it is not already installed

Comment: hey, I got the error, in the ubuntu repository the version of texlive is 2020 but latest one is 2021, I will install from tug.org and it should work then.